# Best Practice for Referencing the Plugin Directory

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory

My plugin uses the following code to reference a file, but I've read `WP_PLUGIN_DIR` won't work if a user renames the default plugin folder. I would also like to replace `/location-specific-menu-items/`with a reference to the current plugin folder.

```
$gi = geoip_open(WP_PLUGIN_DIR ."/location-specific-menu-items/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

How could I rewrite this to make it work regardless of the names of the WP plugin directory and the specific plugin folder?

EDIT:

Here is my final working solution following everyone's input. Many thanks!

```
$GeoIPv4_file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/GeoIPv4.dat';
$GeoIPv6_file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/GeoIPv6.dat';

if (!filter_var($ip_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) === FALSE) {     
    if ( is_readable ( $GeoIPv4_file ) ) { 
        $gi = geoip_open( $GeoIPv4_file, GEOIP_STANDARD );
        $user_country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip_address);
        geoip_close($gi);
    }
} elseif (!filter_var($ip_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === FALSE) {
    if ( is_readable ( $GeoIPv6_file ) ) {
        $gi = geoip_open( $GeoIPv6_file, GEOIP_STANDARD );
        $user_country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip_address);
        geoip_close($gi);
    }
} else {
    $user_country = "Can't locate IP: " . $ip_address;              
}
```

Comment: where did you read that..? if the user renames the plugin folder I think they would have to  be sure to redefine WP_PLUGIN_DIR as well...

Comment: Ah, I misspoke. The problem is that plugins don't always live in the default plugins directory. Here's the quote I read: "Don't use WP_PLUGIN_URL or WP_PLUGIN_DIR — plugins might not be in the plugins directory."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the plugin structure is:

```
plugins/
   some-plugin/
       some-plugin.php
       data/
           GeoIP.dat
```

then for PHP 5.3.0+, you could try the magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> `__DIR__` The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to
>   `dirname(__FILE__)`. This directory name does not have a trailing slash
>   unless it is the root directory.

within the `some-plugin.php` file:

```
// Full path of the GeoIP.dat file
$file =  __DIR__ . '/data/GeoIP.dat';

// Open datafile
if( is_readable ( $file ) ) 
    $gi = geoip_open( $file, GEOIP_STANDARD );
```

For wider PHP support you could use [`dirname( __FILE__ )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), where `__FILE__` was added in PHP 4.0.2.

Comment: ps: note that if you use `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`, then it's a wrapper for `trailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__  ) )` that adds a trailing slash to the dirname.

Comment: woah cool that is almost exactly word for word what I just posted, lol

Comment: hehe I just beat you to it, but this can happen, anyway +1 ;-)

Comment: So `$file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/GeoIP.dat';` would work was well?

Comment: yes that should work @j8d

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
```

Which as is just a wrapper function anyway for:

```
trailingslashit(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also have a look at the functions WordPress has on board for this: e.g. [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/), [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) or [`plugin_dir_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url)

They will help you with determining where your plugin is placed on the server. Those functions are also recommended by the Codex in [Writing a Plugin: Names, Files, and Locations.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Names.2C_Files.2C_and_Locations)

Besides that you can obviously use magic constants from PHP and filtering their output to determine where your files are.

Comment: I don´t see a problem with using `plugin_dir_url()`, it returns the folder for the file you passed, yeah. That´s what he needs.

Comment: `plugin_dir_path` returns the directory, `plugin_dir_url` will give you the URL to the file, which is simply not the same thing and NOT what he needs. it is useful for other things - like image sources or enqueueing stylesheets though.